# Incantation Referring to Three Roses

Tags: prayer-book, kiddush-levanah

In the prayer book Tefillah Yeshara,  in the section for the blessing on  seeing the new moon (kiddush levanah), an incantation (lahash) is included to say at that time. It begins:

> אני פב"פ נושא אצלי שלושה שושנים אחת היא החמה ואחת היא הלבנה והשלישית
>   היא חסד אל
>
> I, *name* son of *name*, carry with me three roses; one is the sun, and one is
>   the moon, and the third is the kindness of God.

(http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7190&st=&pgnum=242)

Can anyone shed light on the context or provenance of this?